# How to install Colorama in Python?

Tags: python, colorama

I downloaded the colorama module for python and I double clicked the setup.py. The screen flashed, but when I try to import the module, it always says

> No Module named colorama

I copied and pasted the folder under 'C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages' and tried to run the setup from there. Same deal. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try executing setup.py from the Windows command line by navigating to the download directory, and running `python setup.py`. What is the output when you do this?

Comment: I ran python C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\colorama-0.2.4\setup.py and it returns 'error package directory 'colorama' does not exist'

Comment: Ok, I forgot to add 'install' to the end of the command line. Looks like it installed, but when I call it in IDLE, it still says 'No Module named colorama'....I restarted the application, but nothing.

Comment: 'error package directory 'colorama' does not exist' indicates to me that you could try creating the directory `colorama` in your site-packages folder. Try separately: both that and renaming the colorama-0.2.4/ directory to colorama/

Comment: I've tried both of those. When I run the setup, it creates a folder under site-packages called 'colorama' and installs all the libs. I go to IDLE and import colorama and again, it just says ImportError: No module named colorama' Very frustrating...

Comment: Silly question, did you restart IDLE between installs?

Comment: `pip install colorama`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Python packages are installed using setup.py by entering the following command from a command line:

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: Hey TJD, I did as you suggested, it seemed to have insatlled, but when I call it in IDLE, it still tells me it doesn't exist. Any other suggestions? Thanks, Mike

Comment: I don't have any problem importing from IDLE.  Any chance you have multiple versions of python installed?  For example, installed colorama under Python25 or under cygwin's python, but then using IDLE from another Python install.  Can you import colorama from command line python without IDLE?  What does your sys.path say?

Comment: TJD, thanks for the though. I do not have 2 versions of python, but you did jog my memory. I have python installed from ArcGIS which has a separate folder under python26 with its own site-package folder. I didn't realize it was there. i installed under that folder and now it works. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: If you don't have `sudo` privileges, and want to only install it for the current user, do `python setup.py install --user`

Answer (score 33):

Installing with pip is almost always the way to go.  It will handle downloading the package for you, as well as any dependencies.  If you don't have pip, see http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html

Then

```
pip install colorama
```

or

```
sudo pip install colorama
```

Ba-boom!  Done.

Comment: If you don't have root access on your linux box, you can `pip install colorama --user`

Answer (score 4):

I just a weird problem with `awscli` and `colorama`. Searching for an answer, I came here. The solution was:

```
$ sudo -H pip uninstall colorama
$ sudo -H pip install colorama
```

Comment: Upon trying the uninstall command I received the message "Skipping colorama as it is not installed.", even though it was installed and returned said error. Proceeding to install in spite of that resolved the issue, when all other solutions failed. +1

Answer (score 2):

Run the following command in Google shell:

`sudo pip3 install colorama`

Answer (score 1):

Re-installing colorama might not work right away. If there is a colorama .egg in `site-packages`, you need to remove that file first and then `pip install colorama`.

Answer (score 1):

If you got the below error on ubuntu 18.04 `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rsa'`, then try:

```
pip3 install colorama
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install for a specific version of Python using the following command:

```
python3 -m pip install colorama
```

In case you need to root privileges, for Linux/macOS:

```
sudo -H python3 -m pip install colorama
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have easy_install (in most case that will work)

```
sudo easy_install -U colorama
```

if you installed pip

```
sudo pip install -U colorama
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced this problem. Following the instructions to install `sudo pip install colorama` I receive the message:

**Requirement already satisfied: colorama in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages.**

The problem for me is that I am using python3 in my header code `#!usr/bin/env python3`.
Changing this to`#!usr/bin/env python` works - sorry, I don't know how to get it to work with python 3!

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, you can use this in the command prompt:

```
python get-pip.py

pip install colorama
pip uninstall colorama
```

You should also check the official site out: [Installing Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Anaconda Environment and use the  following command

```
pip install colorama
```

Answer (score -1):

According to documentation you should always run setup.py for colorama from its install directory.
https://github.com/tartley/colorama/issues/41

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30850486)